# Value of Rd (Destination Register) in load/store instruction (mips pipeline)

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

[Architecture of Pipeline MIPS Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut6u6.png)

I'm working with a Pipeline MIPS Processor and I have the following program:

```html
# $a0 = 0x 805F E371
# $t0 = 0x 8007 4821

lw $t0, ($a0)
```

The load instruction is running in ID phase. In ID/EX register there are many saved register. One of this register is called Register Destination (Rd). I know that `Rs` register contains the value of `$a0`, `Rt` contains the value of `$t0`.

The question is: What's inside `Rd`? I suppose `0` cause it's not in use, but I'm not sure. Could it be `0` for another reason? Could it be a different value from `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lw` is an I-type instruction it use two register operands and one immediate operand.

```
   31-26     25-21   20-16      15-0
 |  op    |  rs    |  rt    |    imm   |
  6 bits    5 bits   5 bits     16 bits
```

`rs` and `imm` are always used as source operand.

`rt` **is used as destination register** and you know what it contains.

You are maybe confusing this with R-type which use `rd` as destination operand.

This is R-type.

```
   31-26    25-21    20-16    15-11   10-6    5-0
|   op    |  rs    |  rt    |  rd   | shamt | funct |
  6 bits    5 bits   5 bits  5 bits  5 bits  6 bits
```

Comment: Ehi Adam! Thanks for the answer. I know there's no an rd register in lw instruction, but an exercise on value of registers asked me what's the value of Rd in lw instruction. The right answer was 00000 (binary), a little strange. But maybe, now I understood why: the Rd register occupies 11-15 positions of instructions. So if there's no Rd, I suppose I should take the 5 more signifier bits of offset, 'cause they're in those 11-15 bits.. could it be a right idea?

Comment: `rd` is not used in `lw` so simple it is,that's why maybe it's told in your answer it's `00000`. If you want to know exact how many bits every register operand take look at MIPS Reference sheet of course you can calculate those from the ` 0x805FE371`

Comment: Still you mix up R-type with I-Type. In I-type 20-16 bits are used as destination register. We don't have any 11-15 for `lw`. I updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: No Adam, I got it! R-type has `rt` as destination register, I know it. This is what made me confused. The only 2 ways `rd` has 00000 value is it's not in use or it's the 11-15 bits of offset. I'll probably write to my professor and I'll write you back to let you know the answer! Thanks for your time, Adam!

Comment: https://www.kth.se/social/files/54948c82f276540590491ed4/mips-ref-cheat-sheet.pdf  Here is a link to MIPS Reference sheet , you can check yours self.it's easy to understand.

Comment: I have answered as you ask in your question title and content (load word /store word) and the use of `lw $t0, ($a0)`. If you want to know the value of `rd` which is used in R-type instruction such as `add ,or , beq` etc. than of course you use 15-11 bits (rd) as destination register which I explained also in the answer.

Comment: Adam, you were right! I wrote an email to my professor and she said the value of `rd` is zero 'cause it's not used! Thank you for your answers!